# Catch/Find someone doing something

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

Is there a difference between '**catch** someone doing something' and '**find** someone doing something?'

My brother always wakes up late. I said:
"If I find you sleeping at this time from tomorrow I'm not going to help you with your homework anymore."

I wonder what difference it would make if I said 'catch' instead of 'find.'

Answer (score 2):

There is no real difference in usage, but `catch` has a heavy connotation of a mis-deed of some sort, i.e. that you think that sleeping this late is wrong, whereas `find` is completely neutral.

In your longer example, I would indeed use `catch` rather than `find` since it is clear that you regard it as unacceptable.

Comment: I would say that _catch_ has more of an implication that it's only by chance that you see the person misbehaving.

Comment: @Mike.  We responded at exactly the same time, but then I went to make a coffee before I hit send.  Your response fits the bill, so I'm not suggesting yours is lacking in any way by saying pretty much the same.

Comment: @KateBunting  `Catch` is also used in deliberate contexts, such as `catching a criminal`

Comment: I know that, of course, but I was referring to 'catching someone doing something'.

Answer (score 2):

Compare these two sentences:

I walked into my son's bedroom and found him reading a book

I walked into my son's bedroom and caught him looking at porn.

(the obvious conclusion is that I should have knocked!)

Catch implies to encounter someone who is in the act of doing something that is considered wrong.

So, is your brother aware that sleeping late is a problem for you?  In your example, using catch is correct if it is inappropriate for him to be sleeping at that time.